# Превратить JavaScript-код в jQuery-код

Tags: javascript, jquery

Может кто помочь превратить этот JavaScript в jQuery?

```js
var d = document;
d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var cirles = [].slice.call(d.querySelectorAll('.circle'));
 
    [].forEach.call(d.querySelectorAll('button'), function (but) {
        but.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var act = this.dataset.action;
            cirles.forEach(function (el) {
                el.classList[act]('active');
            });
        }, false);
    });
   
    cirles.forEach(function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', toggleCirсleClass);
    });
 
    function toggleCirсleClass() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
    }
 
}, false);
```

```css
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.active {
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<span class="circle"></span>
<button data-action="add">Вкл.</button>
<button data-action="remove">Выкл.</button>
```

Comment: А что вы сами уже сделали для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: А "как надо" - это как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/b9q5mw7x/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.circle', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
        var action = $(this).data('action');
            $circles = $('.circle');

        if (action === 'add') {
            $circles.addClass('active');
        } else {
            $circles.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ага, так, спасибо))